# Observe from DialogFragment - where and with which lifecycle owner?

Tags: android-fragments, android-livedata, android-dialogfragment

The android team has created a mess with regard to live data observed from a `DialogFragment`.

I've heard BOTH that you should observe live data with `this` instead of `viewLifecycleOwner` AND the opposite. This "explanation" from Google only adds to the confusion:

> Note: When subscribing to lifecycle-aware components such as LiveData,
> you should never use viewLifecycleOwner as the LifecycleOwner in a
> DialogFragment that uses Dialogs. Instead, use the DialogFragment
> itself, or if you're using Jetpack Navigation, use the
> NavBackStackEntry.

What does it even mean "a DialogFragment that *uses* Dialogs"?  Doesn't **EVERY** DialogFragment "use" a Dialog? Or does a DialogFragment only "use" a Dialog when you override `onCreateDialog`???

What I infer from this confusing explanation is that you should use `this` instead of `viewLifecycleOwner` if and only if you customize the dialog by overriding `onCreateDialog`, but it's totally unclear.

And I'm not even clear whether you should observe from `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated`. Which is it?

For the love of all that is holy, can I get a final consistent answer on how to properly observe live data in a `DialogFragment`? Specifically, in my project I ALWAYS inflate a custom layout for my dialogs in `onCreateView` and I NEVER override `onCreateDialog`.